# Is it necessary to include superclasses on php?

Tags: php, laravel, inheritance, include, superclass

I created two classes

*teste.php*

```
<?php

namespace Projeto;

use Pai\classepai;
//include 'classepai.php';

class teste extends classePai
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        echo 'classe teste<br>';
    }
}
```

and

*classepai.php*

```
<?php

namespace Pai;


class classepai
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        echo 'classe pai<br>';
    }
}
```

it returns me an error UNLESS I uncomment `include 'classepai.php';`

Then I have this class from Laravel (php framework)

```
<?php

namespace App\Http;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel as HttpKernel;

class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{...}
```

My question is how can `HttpKernel` be extended WITHOUT BEING INCLUDED.

Comment: Laravel, as any other decent framework, should use class auto-loading so you shouldn't need to include files manually. In any case, saying that you get an error message and ignoring the error message is basically as much info as saying "it doesn't work".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`HttpKernel` is required in `composer.json` and in code it's included using `autoload.php`. That's why you don't need to include `HttpKernel` manually. If you want to do same on `classeapi` you should add it into `composer.json` `autoload`.`psr-4` section using `namespace` and folder location.

Example:

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Pai\\": "packages/pai/src",
        }
    }
}
```

Then run command `composer dump-autoload` and you will be able to use your `classeapi` like so: `Pai\classeapi`